# Python problem can't run module and output problem

Tags: python

I  write code which will output some data file, but I got error and have no idea what is wrong already looking for 2 hours (you know how is it :) )

```
import binascii
import sys
import time

url12 = "my win dir for file"

def toHex(s):
 1st = []
 for ch in s:
     hv = hex(ord(ch)).replace('0x', '')
     if len(hv) == 1:
     1st.append(hv)
 return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, 1st)

url = toHex(url12)
```

.......etc.

debug output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RED\Desktop\builder\builderUpdate.py", line 22, in <module>
    url = toHex(url12)
  File "C:\Users\RED\Desktop\builder\builderUpdate.py", line 20, in toHex
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, lst)
NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined
```

Comment: this code will not make it past reduce with `1st` being an illegal variable name(in python names start with letters not numbers) and if you want to solve the problem indicate what is it that you're trying to do/ what problem this code is supposed to solve

Comment: this file must execute specific file with data. about the name it is "L" not 1

Comment: The name is 1 and not L

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, reduce was a built-in function. In Python 3, you have to import it from `functools`

That's why you're getting an error

Also, the empty list in your function can't begin with a number otherwise you get a syntax error. It can contain numbers but should start with an underscore or a letter

Comment: I did it right now and same output

Comment: Can you please update your question with the edited code you tried and the error?

Comment: sorry don't understand

Comment: @NugoSikharulidze if you changed your code to use `functools.reduce` and you're still having issues, please update your question to include that new code, and the new error-message.